# Immediate rendering in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, rendering, three.js

Given a sample code like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <span id='canvas'></span>                 
    </body>

<script src="Three.js"></script>
<script>    
    var renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(500, 500);
    document.getElementById('canvas').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(36, 1, 0.1, 3000);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 50);
    scene.add(camera); 

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    alert('0');
    foo();
    alert('3');


    function foo() {
        var x = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(5, 5, 5), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
        scene.add(x);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        alert('1');
        bar();
    }

    function bar() {
        var y = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(20, 20, 20), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
        scene.add(y);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        alert('2');
    }

</script>

</html>
```

(This sample is not a part of the real project, but it will help to explain the problem.)
The goal is to see nothing when the zero alert performed, then to see a sphere before the first alert, and to see a cube before the second alert. In fact all rendering performs after the third alert. But we need to have a result before returning from foo() and bar().

Why do we have to be in global scope to perform rendering? 
Is there any method to render a scene without leaving a function?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this code will provide the effect you are looking for?

```
<script src="Three.js"></script>
<script>  

// insert global variable declarations here 
var loopNumber = 0;

init();
animate();

function init()
{
     // insert standard Three.js setup/initialization code here
}

function animate() 
{
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();       
    update();
}

function update()
{
    loopNumber++;
    if (loopNumber == 1)
        foo();
    if (loopNumber == 2)
        bar();
}

function render() 
{
    renderer.render( scene, camera );   
}
```